# Trigger in sybase

Tags: triggers, sybase

I have requirement where trigger needs to be created on same table.

Here is the condition,

When A code is inserted into table at the same time trigger gets involved and writes B code

Where Type is column which will be having value as A then need to insert Type column only With B value rest thing will remain same .

Please assist

Comment: If this is a Sybase question, please untag Oracle PL/SQL and PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? please confirm that when a new row is inserted with `Type = 'A'` then you want to do ... what?  Update the newly inserted row and change `Type = 'A'` to `Type = 'B'`? or do you want to insert a new row with `Type = 'B'`?  how many columns does this table have?